# node.js - process.on('message'....) does not work outside of infinite loop

Tags: node.js

```
process.on('message', (data) => {
  console('on receive message')
})

generate()

function generate () {
  func()     //method which have while-loop which will takes about 10 mins.
  generate()
}
```

I cannot receive message while func() is working.
only receive stacked message after func() finsiehd.

How can I receive message even func() is working...

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS is a single threaded application.  Therefor running a loop for ~10 min will block all processing of any other code.  You need to release the execution stack to allow other pending code to run.

A very simple way to do that is with `setTimeout` which will stop run the specified function in the future, or `setInterval` which will run it periodically.

```
setInterval(generate, 600000); // Run generate every 10 minutes
```

Other options include `async/await` + Bluebird `Promise.delay` or a wide variety of queuing / async libraries on npm.

If you absolutely need to `func` to be executing then you need to examine other options.  As I said before, nodejs is a single threaded application.  You could do the processing in another nodeJS process or you need to re-design `func` so that it executes in a queue such that the execution stack will be periodically cleared so that pending tasks can run.